# why does my plpgsql function return no rows

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

when the two queries are run independently against a user I get the results 300 and 0 however in my function I am getting no rows returned.

I am moving from SQL Server to PostgresSQL so some things are a bit alien to me!

```
create or replace function getsummary(userid int)
returns table (assetTotal numeric, liabilityTotal numeric)
as $$
BEGIN

SELECT sum(t.credit) - sum(t.debit)
into assetTotal
    from transactions t
    join user_institutes i on t.user_institute_id = i.id
    where i.account_type in (1,3,4,5)
    and i.user_id = userid;

    select sum(t.credit) - sum(t.debit)
    into liabilityTotal
    from transactions t
    join user_institutes i on t.user_institute_id = i.id
    where i.account_type in (2,8,10)
    and i.user_id = userid;
END
$$ language plpgsql;

select * from getsummary(1)
```

Many thanks

Comment: it probably also says the and reached with no return?.. that isbecause you dont have any out argument and dont return anything... you do actual insert into assetTotal table?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, nope just says no rows returned and the execution time. So I am wrong in thinking that the insert x into x fills my table? Now I think about it do I want to insert into a row somehow and insert that into the table to return?

Comment: oh - I thought OP meant he's movng from t-SQL to plpgsql :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I mean I haven't worked with postgres databases before, my knowledge is entirely in mssql/mysql. I am unaware how I can convert a sql stored procedure into a postgresql function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not looking deep to your queries, just pointing missing part. try?:

```
create or replace function getsummary(userid int)
returns table (assetTotal numeric, liabilityTotal numeric)
as $$
DECLARE
 _assetTotal numeric;
 _liabilityTotal numeric;
BEGIN

SELECT sum(t.credit) - sum(t.debit)
into _assetTotal
    from transactions t
    join user_institutes i on t.user_institute_id = i.id
    where i.account_type in (1,3,4,5)
    and i.user_id = userid;

    select sum(t.credit) - sum(t.debit)
    into _liabilityTotal
    from transactions t
    join user_institutes i on t.user_institute_id = i.id
    where i.account_type in (2,8,10)
    and i.user_id = userid;
  return query select _assetTotal, _liabilityTotal;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change the declared types to numeric, but that did the trick!